# ModelState ErrorMessage Culture Localization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, culture, defaultmodelbinder

[ModelState Validation Culture on HttpPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851063/modelstate-validation-culture-on-httppost)

[Error messages from ModelState not get localized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114582/error-messages-from-modelstate-not-get-localized)

I have read these questions and they didn't solve my problem.

My problem: ModelState Validation errorMessages are always in English. Localization does not work.

**LocalizationAttribute.cs File**

```
public class LocalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString()))
        {
            // set the culture from the route data (url)
            string lang = filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Add("Culture", new CultureInfo(lang));
        }
        else
        {
            // get the browser culture
            string langHeader = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0];
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(langHeader);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(langHeader);
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] = langHeader;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Set the view engine
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyCustomViewEngine(SiteSettings.Theme));
    }
}
```

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new LocalizationAttribute());
    }
}
```

I need to set culture before modelstate error start, but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not achieve what you want by `LocalizationAttribute` because, it's too late when you set both `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` method.

When `OnActionExecuting` get fired the `ModelState` errors are already set by the assembly culture.

**Solution 1**

Override `Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)` method in a base controller and set the wanted culture in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

**Solution 2**

Override `Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` in the `Global.asax` and set the wanted culture in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.